# Should <a> tags with href="#" (or other internal links) use rel="noindex, nofollow"?

Tags: seo

For SEO purposes, should `<a>` tags with `href="#"` make use of `rel="nofollow"`, `rel="noindex"`, `rel="noindex, nofollow"`, or does it not matter?

I'm asking because I have some elements on my site where I use anchor tags to trigger mouseovers, etc, and I'm just wondering how the search engines handle those links.

Comment: Never have #'d anchor tags, it's bad practice, bad for SEO and bad for accessibility.

Comment: It's not bad for SEO. It's perfectly fine to use #'s when anchoring to parts of the page or a remote page it's an w3 standard, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp You can use jquery and set a class or ID of the <a> to trigger the mouseover events if you want

Comment: @toomanyairmiles why would it be bad for seo or accessibility?

Comment: @Anagio The stupid thing is using `<a href="#">` for links that aren't really links (probably they're just javascript hooks). No one is saying there's anything wrong with anchors in general

Comment: I agree a # sign alone not anchoring to another section of a page isn't the ideal way to do it. I would avoid the noindex attribute because if the link itself is going to the same page who knows how search engines would handle that. Possibly stop indexing that specific page? I'd use jquery event handlers attached to an ID or Class then simply set the cursor style for that ID or Class to make it look like a link

Comment: @Christofian firstly javascript should be unobtrusive, secondly if there is no href it should be a button tag or something else semantically correct it's bad for SEO because google can't or won't follow it - it's simply ignored and whatever content is behind it won't be indexed.

Comment: @Anagio w3schools is not affiliated with the w3c and is full of errors. It is bad for SEO because it will be ignored and it's semantically meaningless.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html I don't believe Google would let a href="#" hurt a pages value. For example when the canonical rel tag came out Matt Cutts said Google would have final say if they were to follow it, and would account for people using it incorrectly by mistake and not allow a site owner to hurt themselves. I imagine they do the same with internal links. I would imagine a href="#" should not devalue a page and hurt it's `SEO`. Finally if you run a search on Google and view the source they also use href="#" in a few of their own links.

Comment: Based on the answers and the comments here, I don't feel that rel="nofollow" is necessary for `<a href="#">...</a>` links. However, there are other ways to achieve what I need to do without using `<a href="#">...</a>`, so I'm just going to change the pages to replace those elements with something else.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles, Your comment about using `#` in anchor links is *bad for accessibility* is misleading. Actually using `#` in anchor links is good for accessibility because when for example you have a nav bar with dropdowns, the users can use their keyboard and Tab from anchor link to anchor link in order to get to the nav item they want, press Enter and the dropdown slides down, then they can keep 'Tabbing' through the available lnks. This behavior can not be accomplished with any other HTML tag other than anchor links.

Comment: @Ricardo you don't understand accessibility and the functionality you speak of has nothing to do with the presence of #

Comment: @toomanyairmiles dare enlighten all of us then if you think you know. Stop flaming and provide solid proof of your opinions.

Comment: @Ricardo there is more than enough information on this site, overflow and the web to back up my information. Do some research

Comment: It's not about the # sign, but the anchor tag that enables tabbing. But having an empty href attribute is bad. Using Bootstrap buttons and links are styled the same. But thanks to browsers they are still different. If you need a real link next to a href="#" link (with javascript trigger), it's no option to make this second link a button or any other element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Don't nofollow internal links](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVOOB_Q0MZY).
Pointing to a flat # as destination arguably doesn't actually "link" anywhere, but there's still no reason to do it.

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't have links with `#` or `javascript:void(0)` in the first place. You should point the link to an appropriate resource - for example if you are making an image viewer, the link should go to the image itself. If you are making a popup window, the link should point to the URL from the popup window, in case the user has Javascript disabled.

If there is no appropriate resource at all, then you shouldn't be using a link in the first place. Use a span or div element and attach the Javascript event to that. Note you can style it to look like a link with `cursor: pointer;`

And as Su recommends, never use `nofollow` on internal links. There used to be a process called "PageRank sculpting" (which was ridiculous and barely effective anyway) but that is no longer effective at all.

Comment: I would like to point that you may want to use a link instead of div because it allows focusing through the keyboard. The same can be achieved with buttons but buttons are horrible CSS wise.

For all webmaster: please stop using div with onclick, some of us like to be able to use the keyboard to navigate a website.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd always prefer to not include any links that have an href="#", but I guess it depends on context.

If you're doing something clever with javascript with the link in question, which would be one of the only reasons I would expect to find an href="#" or href="javascript:void(0);", then why not, instead of allowing the link to ever appear in spiderable (not sure if that's actually a word) markup, why not simply append it into the page whenever your javascript executes, attaching event handlers and other functionality as needed.

Although using id/anchors as navigation within a page is perfectly valid, I can't quite see a reason to provide an empty one, although without an example this is all pretty subjective/conjecture.

*APOLOGIES*

I don't think I actually answered the question there....

I guess it may well be treated by google as a link back to the current page, but I'm not entirely sure how that would hinder, or help SEO at all.

Realistically, there's not a situation I can think of where it would be a good idea to provide a totally dead link though.

Answer. Doesn't matter, but still, don't do it anyway....!

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have Title Tags within the Link, the # sign won't do anything. It is not a link, because there is virtually no value. You could always use name="".

Answer (score 0):

People who are not sighted use tabs, not cursors and will be tabbing from one anchor tag to another when traversing the page.

Thus, if you are writing pages that are going to be read by folks who are using text-to-speech browsers (such as Jaws) using # tags internal to the page is a very helpful way to structure navigation.

Jaws will announce these tags as the person reaches them.  So you can create a directory of important internal links using the # tags.

You should also use the H1, H2, etc. tags meaningfully because these are also used to create a non-visual index of the content for the person browsing the page.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the actual question.